# What is a Latin phrase beginning with "j" and ending with "am" with this meaning?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

For complicated reasons pertaining to a word puzzle I'm making, I want a Latin sentence starting with "J" and ending with "AM". I want it to basically say:

> Juvenile delinquency is caused by drinking lead-filled water.

So far I have:

> juvenis delinquitur per plumbo aquam

Any help?

Comment: Google Translate is horrible with Latin. I suggest taking a look at [any of the proper online Latin dictionaries](http://latin.stackexchange.com/q/867/79) to find the words you like. We can help with composing the sentence. For example, does [*delinquentia*](http://latinlexicon.org/definition.php?p1=2016132) look like a good word for this purpose?

Comment: Do other Latin-speakers (or non-Latin-speakers) need to guess this sentence for the puzzle?

Answer (score 4):

Might I offer:

> Iuvenes delinquunt quod bibunt in qua fluit plumbum aquam.

It's funky with its syntax, but it works. It translates to:

> Youth are failing because they drink water in which flows lead.

Another suggestion is:

> Iuvenes delinquunt quod bibunt aquam plumbeam.

The problem with this one is that *aqua plumbea* would mean "water made of lead," not really "water with lead in it." However, if you're deliberately trying to be enigmatic, it might work.

While I wrote *iuvenes*, you can easily use *juvenes*, though writing *j* or consonantal *i* isn't terribly fashionable anymore.

Let's also take a look at what you wrote:

> juvenis delinquitur

Here, *juvenis* would indicate a single young person, so you'd want the plural, *juvenes*. *Delinquitur* is not only singular, it's passive, which would mean that one youth is being drunk.